# MySQL replication - Slave won't start mysql service

Tags: mysql, debian, replication

I'm testing MySQL replication on two virtual machines with VirtualBox running Debian 8.2.
Following tutorials, this is how I set the slave's /*etc/mysql/my.cnf*:

```
server-id = 2
master-host = 192.168.56.101
master-connect-retry = 60
master-user = slave
master-password = 123
replicate-do-db = base1
replicate-do-db = base2

relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay.log
relay-log-index = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay-log.index
```

However, doing so also won't let me start mysql. When I run */etc/init.d/mysql start*, it fails. These are the two errors that appear on the logs:

```
error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql/mysqld.sock' (2)
Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql server database daemon
```

Commenting the *master-zzz* lines allow mysql to start without a hitch.

The virtual machines can see each other and ping without loss. I've tried changing the my.cnf's master-user and password, as well as creating different replication slave users on the master server, to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well, turns out the tutorials I was following were a bit outdated. These are the final configurations of my.cnf files:

```
#master
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
server-id = 1
log-bin= /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log

#slave
server-id = 2
```

Instead of setting the slave's my.cnf, I used the mysql console:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO master_host='master_ip', master_user='slave', master_password='slavepass';
```

As per this manual's instructions: https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-replication-excerpt-5.0-en.pdf